# awk script to read data from multiple fields

Tags: awk

I am trying to create an awk script to read data from a txt file and create an output script. How can I read the data from other columns? There could be more columns on each line.

`cat test.txt | awk -F" " '{print "echo "$1"\nprint "$2}'`

**test.txt**

```
test1 1 2 3
test2 2
test3 3 4
test4 4 5 6 7
```

**Output:**

```
echo test1
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
echo test2
echo 2
```

Comment: Why? Why are you using awk to create a shell script instead of just using awk to do whatever it is you want to do?

Comment: I will not create a shell script using awk. I am using awk to to read data and create an output. Output is a script

Comment: So you're getting awk to output a script but either it's not a shell script or it is a shell script but you aren't going to use it. Got it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{print "echo "$1; for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) print "print "$i}' test2.txt
```

Comment: You should use `test.txt` like OP. And it would be nice for beginners to have some explanation why this works.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. This is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

To print all fields from a file with a variable number of fields on each line you'll need to loop through the NF variable in awk, which holds the count of fields on the line.

Also, awk's seperator is by default a space, so that is unneeded.

```
$ cat test.txt
test1 1 2 3
test2 2
test3 3 4
test4 4 5 6 7



$ awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print "echo "$i}' test.txt
echo test1
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
echo test2
echo 2
echo test3
echo 3
echo 4
echo test4
echo 4
echo 5
echo 6
echo 7
```

You've also got a useless use of cat in there, awk can just take the file as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I updated my question. How can I create a loop for only print command?